# Loop Through all users to send email Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mailgun

I tried finding the answer but couldn't. I'm new to Node Js and have a user schema that includes users emails. I want to have a form that has 'subject' and 'message' fields, and a submit button which would then send the contents of the form in an email. I'm currently using Mailgun, and a standard email looks like this:

```
 var data = {
            to: user.email,
            from: '"Lighthouse Studios" <noreply@reception.lighthousespace.co.uk>',
            subject: 'Your password has been changed',
            text: 'Hello,\n\n' +
              'This is a confirmation that the password for your account ' + user.email + ' has just been changed.\n'
          };
          mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
      console.log(body);
    });
```

And my user schema looks like:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    password: String,
    studio: {type: String, required: true},
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date,

    comments: [
      {
            quantity: String,
            received: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
            collected: { type: String, default: "At Reception" }
      }
   ],

    isAdmin: {type: Boolean, default: false}
});
```

Here's the form code:

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Send">
            </div>

        </form>
```

So to summarise, I want to use the form to send all users an email when the button 'submit' is clicked. Thanks for your time reading this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UserModel.find({})
         .select('email')
         .lean()
         .exec((err,users)=>{
            if(users){
              let userEmails = "";
              let recp = users.reduce((a,u)=>{ a[u.email]={}; a[u.email].email = u.email; userEmails+=u.email; return a; },{})
              let data = {
                        to: userEmails,
                        from: '"Lighthouse Studios" <noreply@reception.lighthousespace.co.uk>',
                        subject: 'Your password has been changed',
                         text: 'Hello,\n\n' +'This is a confirmation that the password for your account ' + %recipient.email% + ' has just been changed.\n',
                        'recipient-variables': JSON.stringify(recp)
                };

                mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
                console.log(body);
                });
           }   
        })
```

Hope this one will work